# How to get models schema (type_defs) in form of string?

Tags: graphene-python

#### Example Code

I have the following model.

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String)
    author = Column(String)
    content = Column(String)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
```

with this schema

```
class PostSchema(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

#### Problem

How to to get the graphql schema definition in form of string like this

```
"""
type Post{
id: ID
title: string!
author: String!
content: String!
time_created: Int!
}
"""
```

- **I tried** this, but there is not `type_defs` option.
- `graphene.Field(PostModel).type_defs`

Answer (score 1):

One option you can use is to introspect your schema not just the object type. Suppose you have a graphene schema called `schema`,

```
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType
class schema(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

you can do something like:

```
schema_dict = schema.introspect()
```

This will return a dict version of your schema and the types that you want can be found here:

```
types = schema_dict["__schema"]["types"]
```

Unfortunately, this returns a list of all object types so you might need to process it to narrow down what you want with something like:

```
list(filter(lambda types: types['name'] == 'PostSchema', types))
```

## alternative way

```
def make_schemas(model):
    d = """
        """
    for i, key in model.__table__.columns.items():

        x = str(key.type.python_type)
        x = x.replace("<class '", '')
        x = x.replace("'>", '')
        x = x.title()
        if x in ['Str', 'Datetime.Datetime']:
            x = 'String'
        if x == 'Bool':
            x = 'Boolean'
        d += f"""
                {i}: {x}
                """
    y = f"""
    type {model.__tablename__.title()} {{
    {d}
    }}
    """
    return y
```